# Backup software for photos with preview of added and deleted files

Tags: backup, photography

Looking for a backup program for my photo collection. I would like to be able to see which photos that have been added and, more importantly, which have been deleted since the last backup. This is to make sure that I haven't deleted any photos by accident. Preferably it should be possible to see thumbnails of the photos or at least open them from the application, rather than just presenting a list of filenames.

I'm sure this would be possible to achieve using a diff tool like meld followed up by rsync, but it would be convenient if there was ONE application for it, preferably with a nice graphical interface.

Preferably runs on Windows 7, but Windows 10 or Arch linux would do to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google photos for that purpose. You can select which folders to make backup of, and all recent photos added are shown on the top and you can sort it by date, time, month, year and etc. 
As for deleted photos, you are asking a little more, even after deleting you want to see that photo, which do not serve the purpose of deleting. There is alternative that may serve you is Bin, google photos save all your photos in bin for 60 days after which your bin will be cleaned. You can restore it from here.

Comment: Unfortunately Google photos doesn't do what I asked for at all, maybe I didn't describe it very well. Thank you for the suggestion anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org) is doing exactly what I asked for, except for displaying thumbnails of the photos. It is possible to open them directly from the comparison window though, so that will do just fine. Its free and works on all the platforms I specified in my questions, so this is what I will go with.